# Is there a tl;dr page for the Ubuntu Online Summit?

Tags: community

Recently there was another Ubuntu Online Summit. I watched some of the talks and they were very interesting, but very long. Is there a place where I can find a summary of each talk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no page summarizing the event itself. There is however, the final plenary, which is the track leads presenting the summaries. You can [watch the video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtCi1XBhR0c).